# Automation server can't create object: ActiveXObject creation error

Tags: javascript, java, active-directory, oracle-sqldeveloper, activex

I have a very simple javascript code in oracle procedure which us used for fetching the Username for Active Directory as my application don't have any user interface.

```
htp.p('function disp_alert()');
htp.p('{');
htp.p('var WinNetwork = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Network")');
htp.p(' WinNetwork = WinNetwork.UserName');
htp.p('alert(WinNetwork)');
htp.p('}');
```

It throws exception `ActiveXObject creation error`: `Automation server can't create object`

I tried changing browser setting `script ActiveX controls marked safe for scripting` to `enable` and it worked.

But in my case the application is accessed by users in client network and we can't tweak security settings for each machine in network. Can anyone suggest an alternative solution or any other method for fetching the windows username?

Comment: Since you are after the AD logged in name. May want to check this instead which integrates the webserver to AD directly  https://community.oracle.com/thread/3637062

Comment: Thanks Kris. Sure have a look on this.

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely have to use WScript.Shell for whatever you want to accomplish, you may set the option for your intranet zone by GPO.

You may find the corresponding GPO setting with the help of that site: https://getadmx.com/?Category=InternetExplorer&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.InternetExplorer::IZ_PolicyScriptActiveXMarkedSafe_3

Comment: Thanks Daniel for advise,I will check with infrastructure team they can set any GPO rule in domain network as advised by you. With code w = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell"); i just want to fetch the windows userid from Active Directory for user who logged in and hit the application url, As we don't have any specific User interface in application, Application url is open to all and anyone can access within the domain network.